# linq .Sum() not working with Short properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model that contains a list of objects and these objects have a property that's defined as a short. It looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public short TheNumber { get; set;}
}

List<MyObject> TheListOfMyObjects = SomeMethodThatReturnsList();
```

Now I want to do a sum on TheNumber of all the objects in the list so I'm writing this:

```
var TheSum = (from a in TheListOfMyObjects 
              where....
              select a.TheNumber).Sum();
```

I get an error saying that there's no definion for Sum(). Why is this not working and how do I fix it?

Edit:

I have this that works:

```
var TheCount = (from a in TheListOfMyObjects 
                where....
                select a).Count();
```

So yes, I have `System.Linq` in the using statement. Not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: Do you import the Linq namespace? using System.Linq;

Comment: see edit; yes, I have Linq in the using statments.

Comment: linq. Sum() is per definition working as expected. You should re-phrase your question.

Comment: For those who downvoted, see the answer to understand why the problem was occurring; may be there's something to learn here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sum doesn't have an overload for short (Int16), i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx

Either cast/parse first or do `.Sum(i => i)`

Comment: Pretty cool to just say `.Sum(i => i)`. The overload resolution awsomely chooses `Func<short, int>` for the argument, even when there are overloads taking a `Func<short, double>`, `Func<short, decimal>`, `Func<short, long>`, `Func<short, int?>` (nullable) and others. (Here `short` is deduced from `TSource` by _type inference_ which runs before the _overload resolution_ when the code is compiled).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Indeed, it is clever. When we added lambdas to the language in C# 3.0 we also changed the overload resolution rules so that "best type" inference took delegate return types into consideration. (Unfortunately, adding return type covariance in C# 4.0 can cause some situations where you don't get quite what you want, but hopefully those scenarios are rare. And since covariance does not apply to value types, the int/double/etc scenarios should be unaffected.)

Comment: @EricLippert: but why not let .Sum() work with shorts like it works with int32? Why do we need to do the cast?

Comment: @frenchie: What are the desired semantics for adding, say sixty thousand shorts whose sum is, say, a hundred and twenty thousand. Do you want that as an int, or a short?  If you want it as a short, do you want it to wrap around, or throw an exception when it overflows?  You can avoid answering all of these questions by making it illegal in the first place; sum the shorts as ints by converting them all to ints.

Comment: Ah indeed, now I understand how the design decision came to be. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @EricLippert **If** they were to introduce a `.Sum()` for `short`, it should be like the one for `int` and `long`: It should return a `short`, and it should throw (not wrap around) if an overflow occurs (partial sum gets over 32767, or under minus 32768). If you use `Sum<int>`, you can cast the return value to `short` in a `checked` context, but that doesn't tell you if the value exceeded 32767 during the summation but just happened to get under 32767 again.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That assumes 32 bit integers, when in reality it is platform dependent width.

Comment: @asawyer I was talking about the `Enumerable.Sum` Linq methods in the .NET Framework, specifically the overloads which return `System.Int32` and `System.Int64` (called `int` and `long` in C# jargon). Those method are not platform dependent. For example a sequence `{ 2000000000, 2000000000, -2000000000 }` will cause a `Sum` returning `Int32` to throw, but if you sort the sequence in ascending order, it can be summed with the same `Sum` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var TheSum = (from a in TheListOfMyObjects 
          where....
          select (int)a.TheNumber).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` defined in the [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx). In order to use the extension method it needs to be in scope so you need to add a using to the required namespace.

```
using System.Linq;
```